# get data from checkout form magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

Im creating a new shipping method that use zip code to validate if the zip code has coverage but first i need the data from the checkout form, I found the next code:

```
$shippingId =  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getDefaultShipping();
$address = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Address')->load($shippingId);
$address->getData();
```

I used it to obtain the data but checking the console in chrome show me the next message:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 500

Part of the code is this:

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }


        $shippingId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getDefaultShipping();
$address = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Address')->load($shippingId);
$mage = $address->getData();

$file = 'postal.txt';
$print = print_r($mage, true);
file_put_contents($file, $print, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);


        $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');

        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
$method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
$method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes()) {
                $shippingPrice = '0.00';
            }

            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

How can i get the data from the check out form correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve ZIP code, use `$request->getDestPostcode()` inside `CollectRates` method